# TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I keep getting the following 2 errors for my buttons:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
```

I am building a todo list, each note has 2 buttons 'add' and 'Remove'.
I managed to get the note buttons working when I call DisplayNote once.
Whenever I try to make multiple notes with JS map the buttons stop working and I can't figure out why its not working now. Code is attached.
[todo list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1gFt.png)

```js
import React from 'react';

class DisplayNote extends React.Component {
 handleEdit(e) {
  console.log('sdfsdfdfs');
  this.props.edit(e)
 }
 handleRemove(e) {
  console.log('sdfsdfdfs');
  this.props.remove(e)
 }

 render(){
  return(
   <div className="note">
    <p>{this.props.note}</p>
    <span>
     <button onClick={this.handleEdit.bind(this)}>Edit</button>
    </span>
    <span>
     <button onClick={this.handleRemove.bind(this)}>Remove</button>
    </span>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

class EditNote extends React.Component {
 handleSave(e) {
  var val = this.refs.newText.value;
  this.props.saveNote(val)
 }
 render(){
  return (
   <div className="note">
    <textarea ref="newText" defaultValue="test">
    </textarea>
    <button onClick={this.handleSave.bind(this)}>Save</button>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.edit = this.edit.bind(this);
  this.saveNote = this.saveNote.bind(this);
  this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);

  this.state = {
   editing: false,
   notes: ['Call Tim','sdsdsd', 'dentist', 'Email Julie']
  }
 }

 AppObject = {
  count: 1,
  price: 15.00,
  amount: '12'
 }

 AppArray = ['tim','ali', 'jim', 'tom']

 edit(e) {
  this.setState({editing: true});
  console.log('AppObject', this.AppObject);
 }

 saveNote(val) {
  this.setState({editing: false});
  console.log('Save note value ' + val)
 }

 remove() {
  alert('remove');
  console.log('AppArray', this.AppArray);
 }

 eachNote(note, i) {
  return(
   <DisplayNote key={i} 
      note={note}
      edit={(e) => this.edit(e)} 
      remove={(e) => this.remove(e)}>
      {note}
   </DisplayNote>
  );
 }

 render() {
  if(this.state.editing) {
   return (
     <div>
      <EditNote saveNote={(e) => this.saveNote(e)} />
      <div>{this.props.count}</div>
     </div>
    );
  }else{
   return (
     <div>
      /* Calling it once*/<DisplayNote edit={(e) => this.edit(e)} remove={(e) => this.remove(e)} />
      <div>{this.props.count}</div>
      <div>
       /* Using map to create multiple notes */{this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote)}
      </div>
     </div>
    );
  }

 }
}

App.propTypes = {
 count: function(props, propName){
  if(typeof props[propName] !== 'number'){
   return new Error('Count prop must be a number');
  }
  if(props[propName] > 100){
   return new Error('Creating ' + props[propName] + ' notes is too much!');
  }
 }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are loosing the `context` inside `map` function, you need to define the `binding` for that also.

Use this line in the `constructor`, it will `bind` that `function`:

```
this.eachNote = this.eachNote.bind(this);
```

Or use that `function` like this:

```
{this.state.notes.map((note, i) => this.eachNote(note,i)}
```

Or

```
{this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote)}

eachNote = (note, i) => { //use arrow function here

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mayank! It was indeed the binding

Comment: Or even simpler: `this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote, this)`

Comment: @FelixKling awesome dude, no one can beat you in `js` world :) people should follow your comments and answers to learn some thing new in `js`.